# Same table alias for two different tables (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, table, alias

This example has the same table alias used for two different tables.  I don't understand why this is allowed by Oracle, and if allowed, how the results make any sense.

```
create table Table_A (x number);
create table Table_B (x number);
insert into Table_A values (1);
insert into Table_A values (2);
insert into Table_B values (2);
insert into Table_B values (3);

select * from Table_A ;
         X
----------
         1
         2
2 rows selected.

select * from Table_B ;
         X
----------
         2
         3
2 rows selected.

select *
  from Table_A  T
  join Table_B  T
    on T.x = T.x;
         X          X
---------- ----------
         2          2
         2          2
         3          3
         3          3
4 rows selected.
```

Comment: In Microsoft SQL Server, you get this error:  
Msg 1011, Level 16, State 1, Server SQLSERVER, Line 1
The correlation name 'T' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.

In MySQL, you get 
ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'T'

Comment: Reproduced on 11gR2: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ea8c510d3068eb19567e27d8e4650e5d

Answer (score 4):

[Bug 25342699 : WRONG RESULTS WITH ANSI JOIN USING AND IDENTICAL TABLE ALIASES](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=25342699) (login required)

The public versions of Oracle Support notes are quite limited. [Here is the note](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2229061_1.html) that references the above bug (visible in the full version after logging in).

The bug is "still being worked on".

The workaround is obvious: use different aliases.

Non-ANSI join throws an error as expected.

Seems to be fixed in 18.1 and 18.2 as well.